# Button to Redirect same url string to a different domain

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, product

I have website A (retail) and website B (B2B trade only). Website B is a trade only site with no e-commerce functionality. I want to use a button on website Bs specific product page that will redirect to website As same product page for customers to buy. Both websites use the same database and sit within the same wordpress multisite installation with shared products so the URLs are the same (obviously bar the domain).

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I think about quickly:

```
<?php

$domainA = 'https://domain-a.com';
$domainB = 'https://domain-b.com';

$btn_link = str_replace($domainB, $domainA, get_permalink());

echo '<a href="'.$btn_link.'">Buy this Product</a>';
```